# Apply for Family Member of an EEA National

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, family

When I started an application for my wife to join me, I thought the date of arrival in the UK would be around 20 October 2016. Since I hadn't yet obtained a  National Insurance Number, I could not complete the application.

Once I had the number, I finished the application, but I forgot to change the planned date of arrival in the UK and can't edit the application. I also overlooked that I listed two different address in the UK (first at hotel where I stayed when I arrived in the UK, the second where I am currently).

What should I do now? Should I take the application to the TLS Centre or should I create a new account and complete the form without mistakes?

[image: This is TLScontact centre where i selected longterm visa]

Comment: Are you applying for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/overview)?  Is the EEA national already in the UK?  (It's not actually necessary to have a national insurance number to get an EEA FP for your family members.)  If I were you I'd just use the current application and in the "additional remarks" section or cover letter indicate that you were unable to update certain information, and note which information is correct.

Comment: Yes i'm the EEA national member, and i'm already in UK. Thanks for your opinion. How about if for TLS Centre i applied for (long term visa 6 month >)? because there was not nothing about EEA family permit

Comment: There's no point in applying for a long-term visa.  They cost over £1000, while the EEA FP is free of charge.  Ýou should start at https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk, not with TLS.  What country is your wife in?

Comment: My wife is from Republic of Moldova, and in this country we cannot apply at the Embassy of the UK, we apply at the uk.tlscontact.com and they send the package with documents to the uk embassy in Poland. The think is that i'd applied for long term visa at this centre.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you can't apply at the UK embassy, you should nonetheless begin your application at https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/.  If you apply for a long-term visa, you will be throwing away over £1000. See https://uk.tlscontact.com/md/KIV/page.php?pid=procedure: "Before you create a TLScontact account you should visit the UK government Visas and Immigration website GOV.UK to find out what type of Visa you will need and **to begin the application process**" (emphasis added).

Comment: at the visa4uk.fco.gov.uk i applied for EEA family permit visa, at the uk.tlscontact.com book appointment for the application from visa4uk, where i indicated long term visa

Comment: I suspect that you've selected the wrong category of visa, in that case.  (An EEA family permit is not intrinsically a long-term visa.)  Can you add a screen image, or describe, the page on which you select the visa type?  I did this about a year and a half ago for my mother-in-law, and I don't remember exactly what the choices were.

Comment: @phoog just updated the question with image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47457/discussion-between-phoog-and-radu-nunu).

Comment: you will find a description of how to apply for the EEA family permit at http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/81659/19400.  You have to choose category "other."

Comment: What means proof of dependency? "proof of your dependency if you’re dependent on your EEA family member"
My wife does not working at the moment, so yes she is dependent on me. So what kind of proof should i bring?

Comment: Dependency is not relevant for spouses (or for children under 18).  You only need to prove that you are married.

Comment: VTC: the question is really 'how' and the comments by phoog responded to that and lead OP through the process, but OP really wanted a whole series of opinions.. it became a chat/forum and is still too broad.